# Callback for setState in React inside map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am stuck. Hear me out:

if an array lets say `arr=[{id:100,names:["abc","xyz"]}, {id:101,name:["def","pqr"]}]` inside props;
now my requirement is something like this:

```
onSave = () => {
  this.state.arr.map(obj => {
    this.setState({ [obj.id]: obj.names }}
  });
  this.accessNumIds();
}
```

> The problem is when `accessNumIds()` is executing by that time the state is yet not updated. and I can't put this function in `callback()` of `setState` as i want this function to called only once.

Any Ideas?

Comment: `setState()` is asynchrone, so map/reduce first and call `setState()` only once as @riwu suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the mapping first:

```
const state = this.props.arr.reduce((acc, e) => { 
  acc[e.id] = e.names;
  return acc;
}, {});
this.setState(state, () => this.accessNumIds());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting state multiples times depending on the size of props. I recommend doing setState() once with the desired data (not inside map()). If you want to execute accessNumIds() after re-rendering do it in componentDidUpdate().